# Подписка на метод внутри Flatmap Rx Java

Tags: android, rxjava, firebase-android, rxjava2

Всем доброго времени суток!
В ходе изучения и использования RxJava возникло непонимание в использовании метода `flatmap`.

Цель: выполнить последовательно цепочку вызовов с отслеживанием ошибок

```
Observable<FirebaseUser> createNewUserByEmail(String email, String password);
Observable<Boolean> sendEmailVerification(FirebaseUser firebaseUser);

public void onServerRegistrationClick(String email, String password) {
        getInteractor().createNewUserByEmail(email,password)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnError(throwable -> {
                    if(throwable instanceof UnknownHostException){
                        getMvpView().onError(R.string.error_connection);
                    }else if(throwable instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException){
                        //bad email format
                    }else {
                        //other errors
                    }
                }).flatMap((Function<FirebaseUser, ObservableSource<Boolean>>) firebaseUser -> getInteractor().sendEmailVerification(firebaseUser));



    }
```

То есть после успешного создания пользователя на сервере, необходимо вызвать метод отправки письма-подтверждения на почту `sendEmailVerification(firebaseUser)`, но как получить результат от этого метода? Если подписаться через `subscribe` , то не срабатывает. Сам метод работает корректно, но хотелось бы получить от него результат выполнения.

```
@Override
public Observable<Boolean> sendEmailVerification(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) {
    return Observable.create(e -> {
        firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                e.onNext(true);
            } else {
                e.onNext(false);
            }
        });
        e.onComplete();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас метод `sendEmailVerification` написан неправильно. Вы запускаете асинхронную задачу и сразу завершаете цепочку. В итоге когда асинхронная задача выполнится то в вашу цепочку уже ничего не придёт, т.к. уже сработал `onComplete` и цепочка завершилась.

Вам надо просто перенести `onComplete`, поставив его после каждого вызова `onNext`. А ещё лучше - использовать `Single`, т.к. он тут явно лучше подходит.

Comment: точно, действительно моя ошибка, столько времени убил на этот flatmap, а дело было совсем не в нем( спасибо